# spray-cache: Return old value if the future fails

Tags: scala, spray

We are using spray-cache (can't move to akka-http yet) to cache results from a downstream service we are calling. The effect we want is, if the data is more than 15 minutes old, do the call, otherwise return the cached data.

Our problem is that, if the service call fails, spray-cache will remove the entry from the cache. What we need is to return the old cached data (even if it's stale), and retry the downstream request when the next request comes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Spray does not ship with a default cache implementation that does what you want. According to [the spray-caching docs](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-caching/) there are two implementations to the `Cache` trait: `SimpleLruCache` and `ExpiringLruCache`.

What you want is a `Cache` that distinguishes entry *expiration* (removal of the entry from the cache) from entry *refresh* (fetching or calculating a more recent copy of the entry).

Since both default implementations merge these two concepts into a single timeout value I think your best bet will be a write a new `Cache` implementation that distinguishes refresh from expiration.